# Struct w/ bit field: CPython and C padding differs

Tags: python, padding, ctypes, memory-alignment

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned        bit:1;
    unsigned char   str[8];
} test;

#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
    unsigned        bit:1;
    unsigned char   str[8];
} test_pack;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    printf("%3lu str offset\n", offsetof(test, str));
    printf("%3lu total\n", sizeof(test));

    printf("%3lu str_pack offset\n", offsetof(test_pack, str));
    printf("%3lu total\n", sizeof(test_pack));

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs

```
  1 str offset
 12 total
  1 str_pack offset
  9 total
```

on my Ubuntu 14.04.3 system with GCC 4.8.4.

The (I think) equivalent Python program,

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from ctypes import *

class Test(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('bit', c_uint, 1),
        ('str', c_ubyte * 8),
    ]

class TestPacked(Structure): 
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('bit_p', c_uint, 1),
        ('str_p', c_ubyte * 8),
    ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("%3lu str offset" % Test.str.offset)
    print("%3lu total" % sizeof(Test))

    print("%3lu str_p offset" % TestPacked.str_p.offset)
    print("%3lu total_p" % sizeof(TestPacked))
```

outputs

```
  4 str offset
 12 total
  4 str_p offset
 12 total_p
```

On the same system, running Python 3.4.0.

From what I can tell, the bit field should take up 1 bit. C and Python both pad that to 32 bits, adding 3 bytes of empty space to the struct so it aligns better.

However, Python puts the padding before the string and C puts it after.

Also, with `#pragma pack(1)`, C removes the padding but Python doesn't.

- ***Can I get python to add the 3 bytes of padding after the string instead of before?***
- ***Failing that, could python pack the struct properly so that they line up?***

Doesn't need to work across different systems over a network protocol or anything... Just trying to get the bits to line up on one system, even if I have to reconfigure it somehow. Thanks!

Comment: I solved one problem and created another... I had `c_uint` (4 bytes) as the type for the bit field in python, if I change it to `c_uint8` (1 byte) it behaves the same was as the C version that has `pragma pack(1)`. This answers my second question, but I still want to know how to keep the padding but move it after the string the way GCC does it. Adding `_pack_ = 4` to the class doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Don't use bitfields in such case. Have all your fields be of some addressable type. Use bitwise operations (e.g. bitwise and `&`, shift `<<`, or `|` etc...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that implementation of bit fields is *explicitely* implementation dependant. C standard (ref n1256 draft for C11) says in 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers:

> ...
> §4 A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of _Bool, signed
>   int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-defined type.
>   
> ...
> 9 A bit-field is interpreted as a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the specified
>   number of bits

ok, you want an unsigned type using one single bit, but next paragraph says (emphasize mine):

> 10 An implementation may allocate **any addressable storage unit large enough** to hold a bitfield.

Here a byte is enough, so gcc will use one single byte. But MSVC in 32 bit mode will use 4 bytes and the output of the C program would be:

```
  4 str offset
 12 total
  4 str_pack offset
 12 total
```

**exactly what the CPython implentations outputs**

That means that `ctypes` implementers choosed to follow MSVC here. Two sentences in the modules documentation give a hint on that, in addition to the fact that most examples use Windows:

- a warning in 16.16.1.10. Structures and unions¶

> **Warning**: ctypes does not support passing unions or structures with bit-fields to functions by value. While this may work on 32-bit x86, it’s not guaranteed by the library to work in the general case.

and next paragraph states in 16.16.1.11. Structure/union alignment and byte order

> By default, Structure and Union fields are aligned in the same way the C compiler does it... This is what #pragma pack(n) also does **in MSVC**

The problem is that the `ctypes` module implementers choosed a convention - they cannot directly rely on the compiler here because the size of a bit field has to be a constant - independantly of the platform. You may think that is is a problem for non MSVC implementation and fill a bug report but I also think that the `ctypes` module is mainly used in Windows.

So the only way to be able to process your C structure here is to explicitely force the underlying types for the bit field and declare the first field to be an unsigned byte, and eventually specifies an explicit padding:

```
class Test(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('bit', c_byte),
        ('str', c_ubyte * 8),
        ('', c_ubyte * 3),      # explicit padding
    ]

class TestPacked(Structure): 
    _fields_ = [
        ('bit_p', c_ubyte), 
        ('str_p', c_ubyte * 8),
    ]
```

But that is only a workaround because here `bit` and `bit_p` are plain bytes while the C code requires that only 1 bit should be used, the 7 other bits being padding bits.

Answer (score 2):

AFAICT, the rules for bit fields in C are so vague (and compiler/ABI dependent), that you can never be sure of how they'll be padded or aligned (especially once compiler specific packing pragmas come into play). You can make them more portable by explicitly defining additional padding bit field pieces yourself (to make the total number of bits equal the underlying datatype), but it's all going to be hackery. Since it's all hackery anyway, solving your problem of how to keep the padding, but move it after the string the way `gcc` is doing is pretty easy, define the padding manually:

```
class Test(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('bit', c_uint8, 1),
        ('str', c_ubyte * 8),
        ('', c_ubyte * 3), # Unnamed fields apparently work, go figure
    ]

>>> sizeof(Test)
12
>>> Test.str.offset
1
```

Comment: That doesn't make them more portable, as the rules are so vague that you can't even be sure your bitfields will appear in the order you declare them in. When you care about representation, bitfields aren't your friend. They're merely a convenience for *local objects only*.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a duplicate of this well known problem :
https://bugs.python.org/issue29753
A patch has been validated few month ago but is not yet merged in the official sources.